# Javascript insertBefore last li element html

Tags: javascript

I am using handlebars in my project and I am trying to create pagination links with vanilla javascript. I am using bootstrap navigation on my page that I would like to populate with page links:

```
   <nav aria-label="Page navigation">
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li>
          <a href="#" aria-label="Previous" class="js-previous">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" aria-label="Next" class="js-next">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

This is the srcipt:

```
var pagination = document.querySelector('.pagination');

for (let i=0; i <= numberOfPages -1; i++){
    var link = navLinksTemplate({ pageNumber: i });
    pagination.insertBefore(link, pagination.lastChild);
  }
```

And this is the handlebar `navLinksTemplate` template:

```
<li><a href="#" data-page="{{ pageNumber }}">{{ pageNumber }}</a></li>
```

But, in the console I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore'
>   on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is `navLinksTemplate`?

Answer (score 0):

navLinksTemplate is not a node in DOM. This will work, you must complete the construction of t variable :

```
for (let i=0; i <= numberOfPages -1; i++){
    //var link = navLinksTemplate({ pageNumber: i });
    var t = document.createElement("LI");
    pagination.insertBefore(t, pagination.lastChild);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You would have to use `document.getElementById` and insert the actual node instead of a reference to it.

```
<li><a href="#" id="myLink" data-page="{{ pageNumber }}">{{ pageNumber }}</a></li>
```